# Localizing ObjectListView OLVColumn, impossible due to Empty Name property

Tags: c#, localization, objectlistview

So, I'm trying to localize/translate an existing application, this code is running on a base form, and everything is working as expected, untill it runs into a BrightIdeasSoftware.ObjectListView (it's iterating over sub items etc. correctly) the problem is that on the ObjectListView the columns *should* have a Name set, but it's *always* null.

```
ComponentResourceManager parentManager = new ComponentResourceManager(this.GetType());
CultureInfo language = new CultureInfo("en");
foreach (Control subControl in this.Controls) {
    parentManager.ApplyResources(subControl, subControl.Name, language);
}
```

And when it runs into an ObjectListView:

```
ObjectListView localControl = (ObjectListView)subControl;
foreach (OLVColumn column in localControl.Columns)
{
    parentManager.ApplyResources(column, column.Name/*This is the issue*/, language);
}
```

When I set the Name of the column in the designer code it does work as expected and after changes it does in fact generate the Name code again correctly, but I can't go through the entire project to add the name property to all objectListViews every time one is added to the project.

I've tried scouting for any property that contains the Name value, but failed to find any (it's shown in the designer GUI).

I've tried searching the OLV support forums for a solution but couldn't find one and noticed a lot of people having trouble with the OLV got some help here, so I thought I'd look for help here first.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to localize the Name? Don't you want to localize the Title? Columns in a ListView (which is what ObjectListView is) do not have to have a name.

Answer (score 1):

it didn't auto Add "Name"

```
this.olvColSetPartName.AspectName = "Name";
resources.ApplyResources(this.olvColSetPartName, "olvColSetPartName");
```

give it a "Name"

```
this.olvColSetPartName.Name = "olvColSetPartName";
```